# why index is invoked after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to implement an ajax call to filter products as below

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ShopViewModel();
        model.RecentlyViewedProductsModel = new RecentlyViewedProductsModel();
        model.SearchProductModel = new SearchProductModel();

        var categories = Entities.Category;

        var rootNodes = Node<Category>.CreateTree(categories, l => l.Id, l => l.ParentId);
        var rootNode = rootNodes.Single();
        model.CategoriesViewModel = rootNode;
        return View(model);
    }
        public PartialViewResult FilterProducts(int? id)
    {
        var model = new List<VehiclePart>();

        if (id != null)
        {
            model.AddRange(Entities.VehiclePart.Where(c => c.ParentId == id));
        }
        else
        {
            model = Entities.VehiclePart.ToList();
        }
        return PartialView("_FilterProducts",model);
    }
```

and here i call my method first time in the view(Index.cshtml):

```
<div id="dvFilteredProducts">@{ Html.Action("FilterProducts","Shop",null);}</div>
```

then when a category is clicked i call the same method using ajax and provide parameters as follow:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Shop/FilterProducts",
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#productLoader').show();
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({id: $("#" + data.node.id).attr("data-cat-id")
        }),
        complete: function () {
            $('#productLoader').hide();
            location.reload();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length<10)
                $('#dvFilteredProducts').html("<p>No results...</p>");
            else
                $('#dvFilteredProducts').html(data);
        }
        });
```

What am i missing? everyting works fne but after ajax call index method is being invoked again and clears all the filtered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
location.reload();
```

reloads the page (same as user would hit refresh)

Comment: i can't believe i could't see location.reload() for 3 days, thanks, i tested it now and it works, thank you :)

Comment: Maybe too develop-intensive 3 days :)